# Where is the restart option in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Where is the restart option in Android Studio?  In Eclipse, we used to find that option under File -> Restart.

Comment: What do you mean by "restart"?  You mean closing down and reopening the application at the click of a button?

Comment: Yes.Earlier it was easy in one click through eclipse.Is it available in studio too?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with closing the application and reopening it?  That's effectively what a restart would accomplish, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Thank you for response..I was just wandering where that option goes.was it renamed in studio or removed?

Comment: use:    **File>>Invalidate Caches>>>Restart**

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ, the option should be in the same place.  It's a feature you would seldom use unless your file caches went ballistic (and that *can* happen every now and then).

Under **File > Invalidate Caches/Restart**, you'll find an option that lets you either invalidate the caches (and you'll have to rebuild indexes again), or just restart the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Go to : File > invalidate caches/restart